# How to sort a HTML rendition of a sqlite3 table using flask

Tags: html, python-2.7, flask, sqlite

I am creating a simple web page that will output the results of a predefined query from a table in a sqlite3 database. I can see the table and all is well. However, now I want to be able to sort the query in the webpage. I'm very new to flask (day 3) and have limited HTML knowledge, but I am learning. Can someone help me make these tables sortable? You know, the kind where you click on the header and it sorts the table by that field.

Here is the code for this page.

```
from flask import render_template, flash, redirect
from app import app
from .forms import LoginForm
import sqlite3 as sql3

@app.route('/teams')
def teams():
        #conn=sqlite3.connect('nexus_gamification')
        con = sql3.connect("nexus_gamification")
        con.row_factory = sql3.Row
        cur = con.cursor()
        sql="select team_nm, points from team_points"
        cur.execute(sql)
        rows=cur.fetchall();
        return render_template("teamPoints.html", rows=rows)
```

And here is the html:

```
<head>
<body>
  <table border = 1>
     <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Team</th>
        <th>Points</th>
     </tr>
     </thead>

     {% for row in rows %}
        <tr>
           <td>{{row["TEAM_NM"]}}</td>
           <td>{{row["SUM"]}}</td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <a href = "/">Go back to home page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I was looking online and found this: https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/
I don't know how to apply step one, but if I did then I can use

```
<head>
   <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
   </head>
...
<table class="sortable" border=11>
...
```

Is this a module that I need to import? I'm not really sure... Also, I'm using conda to install flask and am running python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the `sortable.js` and place it in the `static` directory of your flask project. And then you can use `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='sortable.js') }}" />` in your template file.